# Leaflet 1.0 Upgrade spliceLatLngs alternative?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Prior to an upgrade of Leaflet 1.0 I was using the [spliceLatLngs](http://leaflet.surge.sh/reference.html#polyline-splicelatlngs) method to place coordinates within a polyline object like:

```
line.spliceLatLngs(index, 1, new L.LatLng(lat, lng));
```

However with the recent upgrade, [spliceLatLngs](http://leaflet.surge.sh/reference.html#polyline-splicelatlngs) was refactored out because of how the new polylines are with the nested arrays of coordinates.

I attempted to do a alternative like so:

```
var latLngs = line.getLatLngs();

// Because I don't need the multi-dimensional array here
if (line instanceof L.Polygon) {
    latLngs = latLngs[0];
}

if (data) {
    latLngs.splice(index, 1, data);
} else {
    latLngs.splice(index, 1);
}
line.redraw();
```

But with this alternative it seems to get rid of the trailing coordinate. :(

Am I just missing something obvious to splice a coordinate into an existing polyline?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is data assigned to? Doesn't the else statement essentially guarantee the trailing coordinate gets removed?

Comment: @TheBrofessor If the data set is null I expect to remove the coordinate, but if it's true I expect it to remove the data from the latLngs. The data here usually being a latLng

Comment: Can [this](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/458) be helpful ?

Comment: @MarcoL Does that require to change the library code? Because I don't want to change the library code :(

Comment: The link posted by @MarcoL points to a solution that looks almost identical to yours. I tried to replicate the problem, but your code seems to works for me: https://plnkr.co/edit/08gZmiImOTOUCG3zSh72?p=preview Can you maybe share some code & polyline data that gives you trouble? Feel free to edit/fork that plunker code

Comment: @chrki I might be having a problem elsewhere, but that code is a little messy... :( I'll clean it up and post back. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function that will replace `spliceLatLngs`,
here's an example written in Typescript:

```
 spliceLatLngs(polyline: L.Polyline, start: number, deleteCount: number, ...items: L.LatLng[]) {
        const latlngs: L.LatLng[] = polyline.getLatLngs();
        latlngs.splice(start, deleteCount, ...items);
        polyline.setLatLngs(latlngs);
    }
```